# Get other columns from select ng-options

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

In the directive I have the following:

```html
<select class="col-md-3 form-control" ng-model="selectedItemId" id="item" name="item"
                ng-disabled="!selectedCategoryId"
                
                ng-options="c.itemId as c.descrip for c in metaData.items | filter: {departmeId:selectedDepartmentId, categoryId:selectedCategoryId}">
            <option value="">@String.Format(Labels.selectX, Labels.item)</option>
        </select>
```

The metaData.items array contains several columns (itemId - unique, descrip, departmeId, categoryId, department, category, item).

I want to somehow get these columns when I'm selecting an item. I would like to keep my ng-model to be the ItemId (e.g. selectedItemId) as I have right now.

What should I change to get to these columns (I can use ng-change event if needed)?

Comment: Re-reading this question again as I need to solve a similar problem. I have countries list with Id, Description and IsoCode. Is there a simple way to get the IsoCode for the selected item without changing that whole thing? May be just add a function to get code by Id using find method in array (from lodash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to show the others columns you need to change:

```
ng-options="c.itemId as c.descrip
```

to:

```
ng-options="c as c.descrip
```

Your `selectedItemId` model will contain an object when you select an option.

Then you can use the `ng-change="showItem(selectedItemId)"` to show the others values. Where `selectedItemId` is the current object.

<kbd>[Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)</kbd>

Something like this:

```js
(function() {
  var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
  app.controller("Controller", ["$scope",
    function($scope) {
      $scope.metaData = {};
      $scope.metaData.items = [{
        "itemId": 1,
        "descrip": "Some description.",
        "departmeId": 1,
        "categoryId": 1,
        "department": "Department 1",
        "category": "Category A",
        "item": "Item 1."
      }, {
        "itemId": 2,
        "descrip": "Description 2...",
        "departmeId": 2,
        "categoryId": 1,
        "department": "Department 2",
        "category": "Category B",
        "item": "Item 2..."
      }];
      $scope.showItem = function(item) {
        $scope.descrip = item.descrip;
        $scope.departmeId = item.departmeId;
        $scope.categoryId = item.categoryId;
        $scope.department = item.department;
        $scope.category = item.category;
        $scope.item = item.item;
      };
    }
  ]);
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div data-ng-app="myApp">
  <div data-ng-controller="Controller">
    <select class="col-md-3 form-control" ng-change="showItem(selectedItemId)" ng-model="selectedItemId" id="item" name="item" ng-options="c as c.descrip for c in metaData.items | filter: {departmeId:selectedDepartmentId, categoryId:selectedCategoryId}">
      <option value=""></option>
    </select>
    <div>descrip: {{descrip}}</div>
    <div>departmeId: {{departmeId}}</div>
    <div>category: {{category}}</div>
    <div>department: {{department}}</div>
    <div>departmeId: {{departmeId}}</div>
    <div>item: {{item}}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I've decided to go this route as well. I was thinking about it while driving and passed the place I needed to turn :) Anyway, I've decided to do exactly what you posted and you just confirmed it.

Comment: There are some problems. I can not get the item to show up initially. And secondly, when I try to show a different row from the index page, the directive code fires before the data retrieved. Here is output (first time and the second):
Current Card Activity data retrieved..
smDci.js:29 Selected departmentId = 0 Selected categoryId = 0 Selected ItemId = 300
smDci.js:42 Initial selections are about to fire...
smDci.js:29 Selected departmentId = 0 Selected categoryId = 0 Selected ItemId = 0
CardActController.js:223 Current Card Activity data retrieved..

Comment: Please, can you update your question with these code? Remember, now you have `ng-options="c as c.descrip`.

Comment: See my other question - I solved both problems - first using a watch, second iterating through array and re-initializing my variable. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33808879/directives-code-fires-before-i-got-data

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to add more description in the drop down list?

```
<select data-ng-model="engineer.currentActivity"
    data-ng-options="a.name +' (' + a.type + ')' for a in activities">
```

Reference: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2013/06/19/using-ngoptions-in-angularjs.aspx

Edit: After reading again and wanting to use on-change() I assume you need this info in the directive / controller. In html:

```
ng-change="itemChanged(selectedItemId)
```

In the controller:

```
$scope.itemChanged = function (itemId) {
                var m = $scope.metaData.items;
                var pos = $scope.metaData.items.map(function (e) { return e.itemId; }).indexOf(itemId);
                var item = $scope.metaData.items[pos];
                var descrip = item.descrip;
                var departmentId = item.departmeId;
                var categoryId = item.categoryId;
                var department = item.department;
                var category = item.category;
                var theItem = item.item;
            };
```

I just need further clarification as to where you need to pull these variables.